# How to dynamically add classes to HTML elements in GWT UiBinder?

Tags: java, css, gwt, uibinder

JavaScript libraries like jQuery have the ability to dynamically add/remove classes to DOM elements like so:

```
$("#some-element").addClass("make-me-pretty");
```

This is important because it allows you to dynamically apply different styling rules to those elements.

In GWT-land, you might have a UiBinder XML snippet like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:gwt="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <div>
        <span id="">Some content</span>

        <gwt:RadioButton ...>
            ...
        </gwt:RadioButton>

        <!-- etc. -->
    </div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

1. For the non-Widget elements, such as the `<span>`, how can I dynamically add/remove classes in the Java code?
2. Speaking of `<gwt:RadioButton>`, I can't seem to find GWT's reference XSD for UiBinder XML, or some kind of official reference to the legal definitions for all the elements and attributes of `com.google.gwt.*` XML. For instance, where can I find documentation for what child elements and attributes `gwt:RadioButton` supports? And not just for that one widget, for all of them! Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the UiBinder.xsd in gwt-user-`<version>`.jar (At least from 2.4.0 onwards, but I suspect older versions as well).

As for your other question: You can always traverse the DOM using

```
yourUi.getElement().getElementsByTagName( "span" )
```

and find the `Element` with the matching `id`, but that isn't very elegant. I actually have never encountered this situation; it is an interesting question!

Hope that helps.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks @Anders Rostgaard Bystru (+1) - I'll take a look here in a second. Any ideas about the dynamic adding/removing of classes for non-Widgets? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To any UIobject (including RadioButton) you can:

```
yourUI.addStyleName("your-class");
```

in GWT: styleName = class

More [UIObject methods](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RadioButton.html#methods_inherited_from_class_com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject)

Comment: While correct, I believe orionTurtle asked how to programmatically change style on a non-@UiField element in the binder.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this. 
Map your  as a UI field to a GWT 'SpanElement'.

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'>
  <div>
    Hello, <span ui:field='nameSpan'/>.
  </div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

In your class that binds to the above ui.xml file, you could change the class as follows

```
      interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<DivElement, HelloWorld> {}
      private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

      @UiField SpanElement nameSpan;

      public HelloWorld() {
        setElement(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
      }

      public void changeClass(){
           nameSpan.setClassName("newClass");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a html page where you load your widgets into.
You could assign a class in the ****.ui.xml** file exactly like in a html page.

```
<div class="MyClass" align="middle">
    <gwt:VerticalPanel>
              .......
    </gwt:VerticalPanel>
</div>
```

Then write you css rule in you **main.css** file.

```
.MyClass{background-color:black;}
```

When the view is loaded the the **main.css** file will "see" the name of the class and act upon it.